# AngularJS Modal (angular ui bootstrap) with navigatable multiple views on same modal

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I have created a website using angularJS and a menu with ng-routing. Now I need to open up a modal which has navigation paths to load different content on the same modal. How can I accomplish this thing? can I use ng-view?

Comment: Do you have both routes without the modal and with the modal?

Comment: Can we have two types of routes in the same application? I only have route without the modal

Comment: Not really. My point was that do you have e.g. `a/b/c` which should show page without the modal and also page `x/y/z` which shows the content inside the router.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use a combination of ng-if and ng-include something like

```
<div ng-if="mode == 'grid'" ng-include="gridUrl">
```

Comment: make some sense.can you please share a sample demo?

Answer (score -1):

I have added **ng-include** to the current view and then through the controller I have changed the necessary views according to the need.